# Same font aligns differently depending on OS

Tags: html, css, fonts

I've got an issue with getting text to align vertically in the browser. On OSX and Linux systems, using chrome, the text is aligned correctly:
[image: correctly aligned]

While on windows systems, the same element is aligned off center vertically
[image: incorrectly aligned]

If I change the font to a built-in, like `sans-serif`, everything is hunky-dory. I'm just curious if there's something else I could do.

The font is `objektiv-mk2`, an Adobe font, loaded via typekit.

Comment: To be honest I don't see anything wrong with the picture here. But there might be subtle differences in how OS renders fonts. Nothing I would worry about to much.

Answer (score 0):

an reliable solution is that you choose the solution which is not depended on OS or browser, I recommend that use

> display:flex

and

> align-item:center

to make an element vertically center.